# Can Someone help me point out where my code is going wrong with the output?

Tags: c++, algorithm, output

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

using namespace std;

/*

Sample Input: 
2 2 ---------> Number of Arrays, Number of commands
3 1 5 4 -----> length of array, elements to add
5 1 2 8 9 3 -> length of array, elements to add

0 1 ---------> Command 1, row and column (first element of main vector, second element)
1 3 ---------> Command 2, row and column (second element of main vector, fourth element)

*/

int main()
{ //taking input of n and q.
    int n, q;
    cin >> n >> q;

    //make a main array to maintain sub arrays within and use queries on it.
    vector < vector<int> > main_vector;

    //make a sub vector and input it's value's using for loop
    vector <int> sub_vector;

    //declaring a variable to take input and keep pushing into sub_vector
    int input_element;

    //take input length of each vector in for loop
    int length_of_sub_vector;

    // now take n vectors input :
    for(int x = 0; x < n; x++)
    {
        //taking input length
        cin >> length_of_sub_vector;
        for(;length_of_sub_vector > 0; length_of_sub_vector--)
        {
            cin >> input_element;
            sub_vector.push_back(input_element);
        }
        main_vector.push_back(sub_vector);
    }
    
    //variable t and y for row and column
    int t, y;
    vector <int> to_print; 

    for(int p = 0; p < q; p++) //take input of the q following queries
    {
        cin >> t >> y;
        to_print.push_back(main_vector[t][y]);
    }

    for(int u = 0; u < to_print.size(); u++)
    {
        cout << to_print[u] << endl;
    }

}
```

The original Problem is over here : https://www.hackerrank.com/challenges/variable-sized-arrays/problem

I know there must be a better way to solve this question but I would like to learn what part of my code is leading to the undesired output, Thanks in Advance.

Output Should be :

```
5
9
```

Output I'm getting :

```
5
1
```

[Live demo](https://godbolt.org/z/j341TTGYY)

Comment: Have you stepped through the code execution using the debugger?

Comment: Please provide what is the input for which you get wrong answer.

Comment: Please define sample input, desired output, compare it to the output you get.

Comment: Consider instrumenting your code with cout's  of intermediate values.

Comment: Please choose a title which is useful for others with the same issue.

Comment: Print the contents of `sub_vector` before you add it to `main_vector`. Then think about scope and lifetime. (You can fix this by moving one line.)

Comment: *but I would like to learn what part of my code is leading to the undesired output,* -- Downvioting.  You have a rep of 162 so you're not new to SO, you have the test data, you have the program, you are convinced your program will work with a few changes, but you failed to debug the program yourself before posting.

Comment: I'm new to C++, before that I was using Python thats why the reputation is higher for a newbie bro and I was staring at my code for 2 days but couldn't figure out what to do so i decided to ask for help .... :( but everyone is so offended. I apologize for the inconvenience.

Comment: *I'm new to C++* --  C++ is one of the most complex computer languages.  If you're going to develop code like this, it is expected that you know the language well enough to never have to rely on SO to debug the code, and especially if you have all of the pieces ready to debug (compiler, debugger, full program, test case).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are missing a vector.clear() statement in your for loop that inserts values into the sub_vectors.

```
// now take n vectors input :
for(int x = 0; x < n; x++)
{
    //taking input length
    cin >> length_of_sub_vector;
    for(;length_of_sub_vector > 0; length_of_sub_vector--)
    {
        cin >> input_element;
        sub_vector.push_back(input_element);
    }
    main_vector.push_back(sub_vector);
    sub_vector.clear();
}
```

Comment: Can you explain me why was the Clear() statement required? Isn't vector similar to lists in python? can't we overwrite them?

Comment: @KanishkMewal The 1st time it goes through the loop it writes 1 5 4 to subvector. The 2nd time if it doesn't call clear() it just adds the elements to subvector again which still has 1 5 4 in it. So main vector gets 1 5 4 1 2... in the next index. Clear() makes sure that subvector will get 1 2 8 9 3 as intended.